# How to make FK with entity framework in net 5.0 web API

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

net 5.0 web API backend with Vue frontend and SQL database.

I need to add foreign key to my table "Zamestnanci" the atribute Pozicia needs to be from another table named "Pozicie".

```
public class Zamestnanci
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Meno { get; set; }
    public string Priezvisko { get; set; }
    public string? Adresa { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatumNarodenia { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatumNastupu { get; set; }
    public string Pozicia { get; set; }
    public float Plat { get; set; }
}

  public class Pozicie
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nazov { get; set; }
    
}
```

I need to get string from Pozicie and put it to the table Zamestnanci but what I tried it always puts there just the ID.

When creating new record to Zamestnanci within frontend the atribute pozicia needs to be an dropdown element.

Answer (score 0):

For Creating this relationShip (Code First) Look At the Example:

```
 using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

 public class Student
  {
      public int StudentID { get; set; }
      public string StudentName { get; set; }
    
      public int StandardRefId { get; set; }

      [ForeignKey("StandardRefId")]
      public Standard Standard { get; set; }
 }

  public class Standard
  {
       public int StandardId { get; set; }
       public string StandardName { get; set; }

       public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
  }
```

[Reference](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: Well I tried it but this way empty array of Zamestnanci appears inside of Pozicie when i try to create Zamestnanci. "zamestnanci": [
      null
    ].  Maybe Im just not on the right rail, can I somehow join 2 tables in VUE ? What im thinking about is that when i create Zamestnanci i would take name property from Pozicie as a dropdown nad use it to create Zamestnanci but I dont know how.